# How can I set a mock Spring user principal during a JerseyTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jersey

I'm working on a content restriction layer of code that basically prevents certain JSON elements from being returned in a GET response.

For this to happen I need to examine the authenticated user principal that is supplied by Spring's security context, customize my response, and send it back to the client.

So... my question is how can I do this with JerseyTest, where there is no security context? I need in some way to set a mock authentication principal that Jersey will find while processing the GET request.

Here's my test:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;

public class GroupResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    public GroupResourceTest() throws Exception {
super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder().contextPath("/api-resources-test")
        .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "file:src/test/resources/applicationContext-test.xml")
        .servletClass(SpringServlet.class).contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
        .initParam("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true").build());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGroupsGET() {
        WebResource webResource = resource();

        String response = webResource.path("/groups").get(String.class);

        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

And here is the corresponding resource I need to have a mock user associated with:

```
@GET
@Path("/groups")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<Group> getGroups() {
Authentication user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

// do user-based response here...
}
```

With this code the `user` object above is `null`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do do this with the following:

```
@After
public void cleanup() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}

@Test
public void testGroupsGET() {
    User user = 
       new User("user","notused",AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
    Authentication auth = 
       new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,user.getPassword(),user.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

    WebResource webResource = resource();

    String response = webResource.path("/groups").get(String.class);

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

NOTE: If you use a custom UserDetailsService and do not return a User object, you will likely want to replace User with the custom UserDetails you are using.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The Authentication object returned is still null.

It's almost as if there are two separate `SecurityContextHolder` instances running. In other words, I'm setting an Authentication object on one, and JerseyTest is pulling from another.

Is that possible?